# Cache dataset on startup?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have around ~500 rows in a DynamoDB that I need to fetch on each API call. However, these rows rarely change. What is the recommended way to load all the rows in the DynamoDB and keep it in a cache in Java Spring MVC so that when the first service call happens to the API, the data is already cached.

Comment: put them in an arraylist? in general dont think recommended/correct approach from the beginning, get it to work and then see if it needs improvement - that is how you learn

Comment: No I mean, in Spring, how can I preload a dataset on startup?

Comment: just do it inside of a @PostConstruct method so it gets done at a startup of a controller https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there a way to set a cache TTL there?

Comment: not that i know of, but a simple `ScheduledExecutorService` could update the list with specified delay https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial. But since your list will now require concurrent read and write you should use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

Use in-memory Spring Caching.

Here is good start https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial